# How do I change the www directory on WampServer?

Tags: wamp

I have all of my site files in a different location then the c:/wamp/www directory. Is it possible to have it configured to where my website files are instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. Just like a standard Apache installation, there is a `httpd.conf` file. In the WAMP Control Panel, locate the Apache section and select `httpd.conf`. In the file, you will want to modify the `DocumentRoot` directive.

Comment: Explain a bit more? How would I modify it? What would I put in? I'm a noob with this.

Comment: Change the current path to the path with your sites

Comment: Can I put in multiples? Like

Comment: DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/" & DocumentRoot "c:/documents/...."

Comment: @Omn, Nope. How would you expect that to work? When you pull up your site it can only show you 1 page. If you want multiple sites look into Virtual Hosts.